# JavaScript array traverse manualy works, but by loop doesn't

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm putting google maps markers into array, and everything works fine, when i do it manually:

```
var m =[];

   m[0] = new google.maps.Marker(.....

   google.maps.event.addListener(m[0], 'click', function() 
   {
    alert('Markerklik');
    $("#trasa").append(m[0].getPosition().toString()+"<br>");
   });  

   m[1] = new google.maps.Marker( .....

   google.maps.event.addListener(m[1], 'click', function() 
   {
    alert('Markerklik');
    $("#trasa").append(m[1].getPosition().toString()+"<br>");
   });
```

But if i want to loop with for:

```
    for ( var i=0 ; i<2; i++ )
{
// do the same with m[i]
}
```

Im getting **m[i] is undefined** when clicking a marker (m[i].getPosition()).

Any suggestions how to do it automatically with loop ?

Note, that if i put marker into variable temp, add listener to temp and do a m.push( temp ); in loop - clicking on any marker giving me position of last added marker.

This looks like adding a event to m[i] doesn't even check value of i, it's not looking for m[1] for example, but something like variable "named" *m[i]*

if i do all the code manualy with m[0] and m[1] - everythings work fine, there are events connected to m[0] and m[1], but creating markers with for loop with m[i] looks like binding event not to m[0] and after one loop m[1], but adding event to "m[i]" when i is just letter *i*, not a value of i

**Ok, looks like this code from a response works**:

```
for (var i=0 ; i<2; i++ ) 
  {
   (function(x) {
    m[x] = new google.maps.Marker( {
     position: getRandomPoint(),
     title: 'Mojmarkers'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(m[x], 'click', function() {
     alert('Markerklik');
     $("#trasa").append(m[x].getPosition().toString()+"<br>");
    }); 

    return m[x];
   })(i);
  }
```

Anyone can explain why this unusual solution works as i want ?

Comment: use for...in... as suggested in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code below, it could a closure memory problem.

```
for (var i=0 ; i<2; i++ ) {
    (function(i) {
        m[x] = new google.maps.Marker(.... ;
        return  google.maps.event.addListener(m[x], 'click', function() {
            alert('Markerklik');
            $("#trasa").append(m[x].getPosition().toString()+"<br>");
         });
    })(x);
}
```

Comment: closures lose variable memory inside loops;

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you create a marker object in a separate function that returns marker, add an event listener to it in the create function, and then place that object in the array outside the function?

Comment: If i try by m[i] - it causes error on click (m[i] undefined), if trying by push() - click on each marker giving me coordinates of last added marker, not this wich has been clicked

Comment: Like other response shown it, it's working but i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `var` from your `for` statement.

Comment: Nothing changend, each marker is on the map and catch click, but try of getting position causes "m[i] is undefined" error

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
m.push(new google.maps.marker...);
```

And then as Pranay mentions, use the length property and loop through the m array.

Comment: This change fix 'undefined' error, but click catch doesn't work in proper way - clicking on any marker resulting in appending position of last added marker.